# How to insert a datetime value of a particular row column in a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have an Excel file which has several columns including date column. I have to consider 10 columns which I have done as follows also i have replace all the missing values of these columns by -1000:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Dataset = pd.read_excel('D:/Data/city1.xlsx',header=0, index_col =1)
A = Dataset[['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9']]
A = A.fillna(-1000)
A = A.values
```

Now, I want to arrange the data in the following manner:

**Step 1**: If value in col1 to col8 is !=-1000 pick that row (note: col9 will not be checked). Also insert a column and write 0 corresponding to this row.

**Step 2**: If value in col1 to col8 and col9 is !=-1000 pick that row (Note: col8 will not be checked) and write 1 in the added column corresponding to this row. this is done as follows:

```
metrics = np.zeros([len(A),10])
metrics[:] = np.nan

k=0
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    if(A[i,0]!=-1000 and A[i,1]!=-1000 and A[i,2]!=-1000 and A[i,3]!=-1000 and A[i,4]!=-1000 and A[i,5]!=-1000 and A[i,6]!=-1000 and A[i,7]!=-1000 and A[i,8]!=-1000 ):
        metrics[k,8] = 0
        metrics[k,(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9)] = A[i, 0:9]
        k = k+1
    if(A[i,0]!=-1000 and A[i,1]!=-1000 and A[i,2]!=-1000 and A[i,3]!=-1000 and A[i,4]!=-1000 and A[i,5]!=-1000 and A[i,6]!=-1000 and A[i,7]!=-1000 and A[i,9]!=-1000):
        metrics[k,8] = 1
        metrics[k,(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9)] = A[i, (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9)]
        k=k+1
```

From the above code i got this

```
     col1    col2  col3  col4   col5 col6  col7  col8  col9
  0  6.7     2.7    9.6   83     61  35.2   0   3.1   26.5  
  1  1.5     0.5    0     95     83  28.2   0   11.7  25.5  
  2  1.5     0.5    0     95     83  28.2   1   16.6  25.5  
  3  5.2     2.6    2.7   70     55  35     0   5.5   26.3    
  4  5.2     2.6    2.7   70     55  35     1   13.9  26.3  
  5  3.7     2.2    0     89     66  32     0   7.5   26.2
```

Now, the problem is that I also also want to add one more column and write the corresponding date of the picked up rows in the numpy matrix that I have created.

Please give me suggestions.

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (part ugly) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: OK fine. If you are not able to understand my language, I have given the whole code and I think by reading the code you should be able to get what i am asking. Please don't give unnecessary comments.

Comment: So do you think your question is perfect? Do you check links in my comment? If yes, maybe you miss part about data samples.

Comment: May be language wise not perfect. But I think message is conveyed what i want to ask. Yes I visited the link. My question is not about creating a coloumn in dataframe or just inserting a column. I am trying to explain you once more. See I have 9 columns. At a time i will insert a particular row of  8 columns if the given condition of If statement gets satisfied. apart from this how should I extract the corressponding date of that row.

Comment: Sorry, seems we dont understand. I dont say about langage, I say about missing part of question - data sample and expected output.

Comment: I have added a sample output. My question is also i want the corresponding date of that row. Is it still not clear??

Comment: Super, but first sentence in question is `i have an excel file which has several columns including date column.` - So you forget for input data with datetime column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211410/discussion-between-imran-khan-and-jezrael).